# Angular 13 Tinymce 6 add external plugin MathType

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, mathtype, wiris

I have an Angular application and I am using TinyMCE as my editor. And I want add external plugin to TinyMCE [MathType](https://github.com/wiris/html-integrations/tree/stable/packages/mathtype-tinymce6). But I can't understand how can I add this plugin and to use?

When I use this code:

```js
export class PageComponent {
  tinymceConfig = {};
  constructor(private request: RequestService) {
    this.tinymceConfig = {
      external_plugins: {
        'tiny_mce_wiris': 'node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-tinymce6/plugin.min.js',
      },
      toolbar: 'tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry',
      draggable_modal: true,
      extended_valid_elements: '*[.*]',
      plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount tiny_mce_wiris',
      language: 'ru',
    };
  }

  async testEvent() {
    await this.request.postRequest(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth/account/islogging`, []);
  }
}
```

```html
<editor
      [init]="tinymceConfig"
></editor>
```

And this error:
Failed to load plugin: tiny_mce_wiris from url node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-tinymce6/plugin.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this url:
`https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js`

instead of:
`node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-tinymce6/plugin.min.js`

About it you can check this guide:
https://docs.wiris.com/mathtype/en/mathtype-integrations/mathtype-web-interface-features/external-integration.html